# If $m= a_1x+b_1y$, $n= a_2x + b_2y$ and $a_1b_2-a_2b_1=1$ then prove that $(m,n)=(x,y)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$$
\begin{cases}
m=&a_1x+ b_1y \\ n =& a_2x + b_2y
\end{cases} \qquad\text{and}\qquad
a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1 = 1
$$

I tried to substitute the value of $x$ in eq-1 to eq-2 and got
$na_1+ma_2=y$

**source: Challenges and Thrills Of Pre-College Mathematics (Exercise 2.2 Q-20)**

Comment: You made a mistake, that's not the value $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $(x,y)$ divides every linear combination of $x$ and $y$, so clearly $(x,y)$ divides $m$ and $n$. Then it divides $(m,n)$.

Now solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $n$ and $m$ and repeat the argument.

Comment: i did not usnderstand your last statement
did u want to say that i solve for x from eq1 and eq 2?

Comment: Yes, solve the system of equations to get $x$ and $y$ as linear combinations of $m$ and $n$.